# Zend Framework 2: delegate as router constraint

Tags: php, constraints, router, zend-framework2

In the Zend Framework 2 Router there is an option to add constraints on a route part.
Now these constraints check for a regex condition.
Is there a way to use a delegate function as check?

Like this:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'album' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => function ($c) { 
                            if ($c == "testets")
                            {
                               return TRUE;
                            } else
                            {
                               return FALSE;

                            }
                        },
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    )
);
?>
```

Or is there a router library that has this as functionality?

Comment: The segment router tries to build a regex from the constraints -- in all cases. I'm not sure if there's another router which implements such a feature, however, I don't think that program logic (closures/anonymous functions) belong into configuration files. If you describe what you're trying to do, we might find another solution.

Comment: Okay thanks! I will try to catch my own route before I let the zend router try to catch routes..